# Sketches not uploading to Micro from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uploading, ubuntu

I recently bought an Arduino Micro to see what all the fuss was about and I figured I'd use it with Ubuntu on an older Dell Latitude. I was able to install all of the files using some tutorials but I have this problem uploading sketches. After plugging in the board, the green top LED is consistently flashing so it seems to be working, but when I try to upload a sketch I get the following error

```
Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: Send: . [1b] 
avrdude: Send: S [53] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried pressing reset during the send as some forums have suggested but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: I just successfully compiled and uploaded the blink sketch to a Mega on 14.04, so the update shouldn't be an issue. Are you using the correct serial interface and board type?

Comment: Unplug Arduino; type `sudo dmesg -c; clear`. Plug in Arduino, wait a couple seconds, then type `dmesg` and copy the output into your question. Also add the output for `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: @jippie how do you determine the correct serial interface?

Comment: It is in the `dmesg` output that you get when following above hint.

Comment: @jippie thanks for helping. not near the board at this time but i'll try and comment in a bit

Comment: `lsusb` is also useful (you may need to `apt-get` it first). It lists all currently connected USB devices. You should see the arduino there when you connect it (it may be called "FTDI Device" (the serial interface device) though)..

Answer (score 2):

I have a Micro and Ubuntu 14.04. I have successfully uploaded sketches to the Micro using IDE 1.0.6. Thus that combination should work.

I suggest you get the sketch compiling OK. Then hold down the Reset button on the Micro, start an upload with your other hand, and release Reset when it says "Uploading".

---

Try typing

`lsusb | grep Arduino`

I found with a sketch uploaded which opens the Serial port:

`Bus 003 Device 087: ID 2341:8037 Arduino SA`

If you hit Reset and wait a second, then do the lsusb again you see a different device:

`Bus 003 Device 086: ID 2341:0036 Arduino SA`

That one (the 0036 one) is the one it will upload to. You might get 0037 rather than 0036 because I reflashed the bootloader to be the Leonardo one, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to fix this is revert back to Ubuntu 12.04.

There is something about 14.04 that does not play nice with the Micro.

I've tried running avrdude on the command line as well with no luck. The Arduino IDE code jumps through some hoops to detect the proper USB port, so timing is probably critical. I don't know the secret sauce for 14.04 though. The micro is tricky since USB is disconnected and reconnected during programming.

If anybody has better luck with this please update.